# Next.js reverse proxy with base URL not routing correctly to /api route

Tags: next.js

I'm attempting to set up a reverse proxy for several services, and one of them is a Next.js application that includes a /api route. I'm trying to set a base URL /base-url for the app.

In my next.config.js, I've added:

```
const nextConfig = {
  // other config properties...
  basePath: "/base-url",
  // env: ... (any other relevant environment configs you might have)
};
```

Additionally, in .env.local, I've set:

```
NEXTAUTH_URL=host/port/base-url/api/auth
NEXTAUTH_URL_INTERNAL=host/port/base-url/api/auth
```

Im using  `signIn()  from "next-auth/react"` to login.

However, when the application runs, it attempts to route to host/port/api/auth instead of including the base-url.

It seems like the base URL is not being recognized or applied.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to resolve this or what might be causing this behavior?

Thank you in advance!